# How to return a Boolean for a page that is a subpage thru its name?

Tags: php, functions, pages

I am attempting to check for a page that is a subpage using its name. For example

```
https://www.myexample.com/mypage/subpage_anything_1/andso_on
```

Here `www.myexample.com` is the web domain, `mypage` is the page and `subpage_anything_1` is the subpage. We can check if we are on a particular page using is_page() like

```
if(is_page('mypage')){//mycode}
```

When I do the same for a page name that is a subpage like

```
if(is_page('subpage_anything_1')){//mycode}
```

The condition does not work and from my guess, its returning as false even when I am on that subpage.

There is a [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916783/check-if-a-page-is-a-parent-or-if-its-a-child-page) in stockoverflow that uses this code

```
<?php

global $post;     // if outside the loop

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
    // This is a subpage

} else {
    // This is not a subpage
}
?>
```

but I think it would return true for any subpage, what I am attempting instead a is Boolean check for a specific subpage only via its name.

What is the best solution to this?

I tried:

```
is_page('mypage/subpage_anything_1') //does not work
is_child_page('subpage_anything_1') //I did not see any documentation
```

Comment: I think `is_page( 'subpage_anything_1' )` should work, but where are you running it? Are you using e.g. `query_posts()` on that page, that could override the main query ? Does it work on a vanilla install (without plugins and with the default theme)?

Comment: Checking for a `post_parent` property that is not equal to 0 on the `WP_Post` object is the best way to check if a page is a child page. As you've mentioned `is_child_page()` does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that the child page is `subpage_anything_1` to check if we are on that page we can use `strpos` to the requested `URI`

```
strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"subpage_anything_1");
```